# JSOUP Issues - Could not find or load main Class

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm having an issue getting JSOUP going on my computer.  I've downloaded JSOUP1.8.3 from the web and have tried many things to get it going.

I'm running JRE7 on Windows 7.  I feel like I learn more using the command line so I've stuck with that.  I type my programs in NotePad++ and use the command line to run them.

Here's what I've tried:
1)setting CLASSPATH to point to my JSOUP.jar file.  This works with compiling but when I try to run my file I get the error "Could not find or load main Class"
2)unpacking the JAR file, adding the JSOUP folder to the ORG folder then recompiling.  This didn't work and caused an error (Cant remember the error but my computer didn't like it.)
3)using the -cp switch.  Again this works for compiling but not for running.

To compile:

```
javac -cp c:\js\jsoup.jar WS1.java
```

This works with no issues.  When I try to run it with

```
java -cp c:\js\jsoup.jar WS1
```

I get the error "Could not find or load main class."

I'm not sure what other info you need to help me with this issue.  I've been working on this for hours and just can't figure it out.  Let me know if you need more info - Thanks - JF

Comment: Of course, you've got `main` method in `WS1`?

Comment: I do.  Funny thing is... I had to double check before I answered :)

Comment: If i leave out the -cp flag it attempts to run but fails because it can't find the JSOUP library.

Comment: Can you post the source code of `WS1`?

Comment: I copied this from another website.  Can't remember where to give them credit. Only reason I'm running this is to get JSOUP to run.

Comment: Ok, try `java -cp c:\js\jsoup.jar;. WS1` You need to add current directory to the classpath.

Comment: That was it. You are awesome. I changed my classpath to this to avoid having to use -cp everytime. C:\js\jsoup.jar;.;    The period was key to fixing it

Comment: You really should consider using an IDE instead of a text editor.. You'll spend less time fixing problems like this one, and more time actually writing code.

Comment: That may be true for some people but I learn so much more by doing it this way.  For example, with this specific situation, I was simply trying to download JSOUP and get it running on my computer.  Had I been using an IDE, such as Eclipse, I could have made a couple of clicks and gotten it running.  Using the text editor and command line, I now understand how to pack/unpack JAR files. I learned that the dot means current directory.  I learned what the Import statement does and where the JVM looks for this data. If I had used IDE, I wouldn't have learned this and many more things.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Dariusz this problem is resolved.  In order to use a JAR file through the command line you have two options:

1)use the -cp switch.  For example, to compile:

```
javac -cp c:\yourFolder\yourJarFile.jar yourSourceCode.java
```

Then to run your java program:

```
java -cp c:\yourFolder\yourJarFile.jar;. yourClassFile
```

yourJarFile in this case was jsoup.jar

yourClassFile was WS1 and

yourSourceCode was WS1.java

2) Your second option is to create/add the following to your classpath system variable:

```
c:\yourFolder\yourJarFile.jar;.;%classpath%
```

Option 2 is the one I went with.  This allows me to not have to use the -cp flag everytime I compile/run my java code.

The main thing that was holding me up here was the period or dot.  I knew that I needed to add the current directory but didn't know how.  So, make sure that you add the location of your added JAR file and the period/dot for the current directory and you'll be good to go.

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP!!!
JF