# Running a java class that requires a jar file?

Tags: java, csv, jar

I haven't run Java in ages, and was hopeful to test a small CSV reader with a simple class.  The CSV reader in question is this one here http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

I've create a small class named DecryptCsv, that's really just a main method that tries to create a CSVReader.

I've got the

```
import com.opencsv.*;
```

at the top, and am able to compile my file with `javac -cp "./opencsv-3.6.jar" DecryptCsv.java`

If I try to run it without the jar, using `java DecryptCsv` it understandably crashes with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opencsv/CSVReader
```

If I try to set the class path when running though, I don't get what I expect.  This:

```
java -cp ".;./opencsv-3.6.jar" DecryptCsv
```

Yields this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class DecryptCsv
```

What's the proper way to run the main method in this simple class, that has this jar file requirement?

Thanks for the help!

Here's test class code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.*;

public class DecryptCsv
{
    public DecryptCsv()
    {
        // foo
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader( "file.txt" ), ',');
        }
        catch( Exception exc )
        {

        }
        System.out.println( "success" );
    }

}
```

The jar can be downloaded at http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/

Comment: I think your running class from command prompt? Before compiling your class set Classpath for that jar, then hit java c

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641095/jsoup-issues-could-not-find-or-load-main-class#comment57028368_34641095

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  This here, has the same problem: `java -cp "opencsv-3.6.jar;." DecryptCsv`  which seems to be the conclusion in that question?  "Could not find or load main class DecryptCsv"

Comment: Am on OS X if that makes any difference, using Java 8

Comment: That does make a difference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux

Comment: That was it nos.  Damn.  Answer it up I'll dish marks